# Inky в Unity не обновляет переменные

Tags: unity3d

<3

В Inky попытка изменить переменную имеет странный эффект: переменная меняет значение, да не до конца.

Нужно сказать, что меня два связанных ink-файла: в первом история, во втором глобальные переменные.

Здесь часть кода панели выбора имени игрока. В InputField вводится имя, при нажатии на кнопку на панели срабатывает метод TakeNameOfPlayer.

```
public class NameChoosingPanel : MonoBehaviour
{
private TMP_InputField _inputText;
[SerializeField] private StoryUnityEvent _onNameChoosing;
...
    public void TakeNameOfPlayer(Story varList)
    {
    var nameOfPlayerVarJSON = "PLAYERS_NAME";
    var inputText = _inputText.text;

        if (inputText != string.Empty)
        {
        varList.variablesState[nameOfPlayerVarJSON] = inputText;
        Debug.Log(varList.variablesState[nameOfPlayerVarJSON]);
        _onNameChoosing.Invoke(varList);
        }
    }
}
```

Тут и возникает недопонимание между мной и программой: в логах выводится правильное значение, то есть то, которое я ввёл, но файл с историей тянет из файла с переменными изначальное значение, а не то, которое прописал в InputField я.

Проще говоря выглядит так: в логах имя игрока - Андрей, в истории - ИМЯ_ИГРОКА.

При попытке сохранить состояние переменных ничего не меняется. Ниже код сохранения:

```
public class InkDirector : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Story _varList;

    public void ChangeGlobalVariablesOfStory(Story varList)
    {
        string newState = varList.state.ToJson();
        varList.state.LoadJson(newState);
        _varList = varList;
    }
}
```